# Help changing NSTimer for textLabel. Code included

Tags: iphone, xcode

want to change my NSTimer code to to use applicationSignificantTimeChange

This is what I have right now.

Basically I want to change the timer, instead of changing every 5 seconds for example I want these textLabels to change at 12am every night anyone help me out?

```
//h file

NSTimer *timer;

IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

//m file

- (void)onTimer {

    static int i = 0;

    if ( i == 0 ) { 
        textLabel.text = @"iphone app";
    }

    else if ( i == 1 ) {
        textLabel.text = @" Great App!";
    }

    else if ( i == 2 ) {
        textLabel.text = @" WOW!";
    }

    else {
        textLabel.text = @" great application again!!";
        i = -1;
    }

    i++;
}


timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 13):

There are two things you can do to respond to a applicationSignificantTimeChange:

(1) Just implement applicationSignificantTimeChange: in your app delegate if you have a connection to the view controller that should be updated.

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
  yourViewController.textLabel.text = @"random text";
}
```

(2) Subscribe to the UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification notification in the view controller that should get the update. You could perhaps put that code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onSignificantTimeChange:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)onSignificantTimeChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.textLabel.text = @"random text";
}
```

You also need to call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

somewhere when your view controller is not longer needed.

Comment: I like this better than my answer.  If the iPhone can notify you of the time, then all the better!

Answer (score 0):

the selector for the timer should be:

```
-(void) onTimer:(NSTimer *) timer
{
   // yourcode

}
```

and called with:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

you need the "onTimer**:**"

---

[EDIT]

for calling a function that will go off at 12:am, for low-performance (i.e. not 12:00:00:0000) you could do the following for like an app that sits in the background:

```
NSTimeInterval minute = 60.0f
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:minute target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]

-(void) onTimer:(NSTimer *) timer
{
   NSDate *midnight = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"today at 12:00 am"]; // unsure of this line
   if ([midnight timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] < 30.0f)
      // set off alarm.

}
```

Comment: And with the "onTimer" do i put where do i put the 12am into the TimeInterval?

Comment: added some edits above.  Untested code, mind you.  You'll have to fiddle with the time intervals, and maybe use "today at 11:59pm" instead of midnight.

Comment: `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` is (as in 'should not be used') not available on the iphone.

Comment: nuts.  You'll have to use something else then, sorry.  lots of string parsing or something to get the "DAY" from NSDate and supply the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward to me -- just create an NSDate for midnight, calculate the time interval of 24 hours in seconds, and create the NSTimer with
`- (id)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`

Comment: any example will be helpful if any