# How can I change a label with a date once the system date changes in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, nsdate

I have a simple query but don't know how to do it.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
1) I have a UILabel with todays date i.e. "29/04/12"
2) At midnight I want that label to update by itself to "30/04/12" without needing to change view or press anything.

It's step 2 that I don't know how to do. I have idea's of how it would be done such as potentially getting a system notification of the date change (if this is even possible) or using some sort of timer as a trigger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the problem with `NSData date` ?

Comment: @Legolas Sorry I don't know what to make of your question, what can `NSData date` do for me in terms of updating at midnight?

Comment: Your application cannot update itself in background for obvious reasons with ios multitasking. You will most likely update your view when the application is running, or when the user views it. You could just update the label with `NSDate date`.

Comment: I mean, you dont have to update anything. `NSDate date` will always return the current time, and you can just assign that to your label.

Comment: @Legolas I'm curious about what you're saying with the word assign. I know that `[NSDate date]` will always return the current date but it needs to be called doesn't it? This is how i'm doing it now but this means that I would need to call this method after a date change to display the current date. My guess is that you have a different way that avoids calling it.
    `NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateLabel setText:str];`

Comment: Yes, You will need to call the `NSDate date`. Just setting it in the viewWillAppear of that viewcontroller should fix the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are only interested in being notified when midnight arrives (or a couple other cases), then you can override UIApplicationDelegate's `- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application` method so that it causes your labels to update. Of course, you'll also want to update the labels whenever the application re-enters the foreground, since this method won't be called if your app is in the background when the date changes.

Comment: +1, here is a good example of how to do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145985/help-changing-nstimer-for-textlabel-code-included/4146345#4146345

Comment: The doc says: **If your application is currently suspended, this message is queued until your application returns to the foreground, at which point it is delivered.** so it will be called when the app re-enters foreground

Comment: I want to call notifications daily basis even if app is not in fourground since week but notifications should be triggered at specific time daily. help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857236/trigger-local-notifications-automatically-daily-on-dynamic-time-given-in-arrays